# SQL smallest time in two times

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
Declare @time1 datetime;
Declare @time2 datetime;

right(@time1,7) = 9:00 Am
right(@time2,7) = 3:10 Pm

case when @time1 > @time2 then 1 else -1 end as small
```

my required ans is -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compare dates as date type:

Just do (**[Fiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/22847)**):

```
Declare @date1 datetime = '20131017 09:00:00'
Declare @date2 datetime = '20131017 15:00:00'

--right(@time1,7) = 9:00 Am
--right(@time2,7) = 3:10 Pm

select case when @date1 > @date2 then 1 else -1 end as small
```

Also you can use **[Datediff()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)** function like;

```
select case when datediff(second, @date1, @date2) > 0 then -1 else 1 end as small
```

Comment: thanks my code itself working

Answer (score 0):

### SQL Server 2005

I'll start with the verbose method that shows each step separately.

```
DECLARE @time1 datetime;
    SET @time1 = Current_Timestamp;
DECLARE @time2 datetime;
    SET @time2 = DateAdd(hh, -29, @time1);

; WITH dateparts AS (
  SELECT @time1 As time1
       , DatePart(hh, @time1) As hh1
       , DatePart(mi, @time1) As mi1
       , DatePart(ss, @time1) As ss1
       , DatePart(ms, @time1) As ms1
       , @time2 As time2
       , DatePart(hh, @time2) As hh2
       , DatePart(mi, @time2) As mi2
       , DatePart(ss, @time2) As ss2
       , DatePart(ms, @time2) As ms2
)
, construct_time_only AS (
  SELECT time1
       , DateAdd(hh, hh1, DateAdd(mi, mi1, DateAdd(ss, ss1, DateAdd(ms, ms1, 0)))) As timeonly1
       , time2
       , DateAdd(hh, hh2, DateAdd(mi, mi2, DateAdd(ss, ss2, DateAdd(ms, ms2, 0)))) As timeonly2
  FROM   dateparts
)
SELECT time1
     , time2
     , timeonly1
     , timeonly2
     , CASE WHEN timeonly1 > timeonly2 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END As small
FROM   construct_time_only
;
```

The idea here is that we set a common base date for comparison. In this scenario we use `1900-01-01` (i.e. `Cast(0 As datetime)`) as our common date.

The reason for a common date is to cater for scenarios where the date parts of our start points are different.

### SQL Server 2008

SQL Server 2008 ntroduced the new `date` and `time` data types. We can simply `Cast()` to `time` and compare the results

```
DECLARE @time1 datetime = Current_Timestamp;
DECLARE @time2 datetime = DateAdd(hh, -1, @time1);

SELECT @time1 As time1
     , Cast(@time1 As time) As timeonly1
     , @time2 As time2
     , Cast(@time2 As time) As timeonly2
     , CASE WHEN Cast(@time1 As time) > Cast(@time2 As time) THEN 1 ELSE -1 END As small
```

Comment: using sql server 2005

Comment: @Venkat 2005 solution added.